# Put extensions in some logical groups, so that only extensions that have same group can call each other in FusionPBX

Tags: voip, sip, telephony

I need to use **FusionPBX** as **SIP registar** *(Session Initiation Protocol)* or **SIP server**, to route **SIP** calls to appropriate **SIP** accounts (extensions).

Currently every extension has possibility to call any registered extensions and everything works fine. But for my purposes I need to set some logic to enabling extensions to call only some group of extensions. My idea is to mark/put extensions in some kind of groups so that only extensions from same group can call each other.

Here is example:

Suppose that there are 4 extensions with numbers 101, 102, 103, 104 and 105.

- Extension 101 is in groupA and groupB.
- Extension 102 is in groupA.
- Extension 103 is in groupB.
- Extension 104 is in groupA.
- Extension 105 is in groupC.

I need to set that:

- extension 101 can call and be called by all users from groupA and groupB, which means extensions 102, 103 and 104
- extension 102 can call and be called by all users from groupA, which means extensions 101 and 104
- extension 103 can call and be called by all users from groupB, which means extension 101.
- extension 104 can call and be called by all users from groupA, which means extensions 101 and 102
- extension 105 can call and be called by all users from groupC, which means nobody because there is no extension whit group C in current example

It is important to note that **extension can be in multiple groups** which means that it can call and accept calls from extensions from both groups. Also all extensions are internal.

Is it possible to achieve this scenario and how?

I tried setting extension's call group but that resulted with scenario where for example when I call extension in groupA all extensions from that group starts to ring which is not what I wanted.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.